# S3 and large files backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have large files and I am looking for a place where I could store files (databases dumps). AWS S3 is good for backups? I have already exceeded all limits.

I have a few questions:

1. I am using API and CLI. Which solution is cheaper to send files via API? "aws s3api put-object" or "aws s3 cp"?
2. "2,000 Put, Copy, Post or List Requests of Amazon S3". How is consumption calculated? In HTTP requests or bytes? Ac Currently, Currently, I have level of consumption for 20 files per day: 2,000.00/2,000 Requests.
3. Are there any paid plans?

Comment: try to calculate https://calculator.aws/#/

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know is at the Request Pricing section of the [S3 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) page.

> Amazon S3 request costs are based on the request type, and are charged
>   on the quantity of requests or the volume of data retrieved as listed
>   in the table below. When you use the Amazon S3 console to browse your
>   storage, you incur charges for GET, LIST, and other requests that are
>   made to facilitate browsing. Charges are accrued at the same rate as
>   requests that are made using the API/SDK.

Specific pricing is available at that page (not included here because it will change over time).